# Passing one variable to multiple UserControls - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainWindow` and 7 UserControls with their own VM's.

My `MainWindow` has two Strings (email and language) which I need in all 7 UserControls. I found a solution (simple `Dependency Properties` for each `UserControl`) but I don't want to do that 7 times for each `UserControl` because that doesn't seem right for me. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "UserControl with their own VM". That's already wrong. A UserControl should never have its own view model. It usually exposes a set of dependency properties that are bound to an external view model. Alternatively, its child elements might directly bind to a view model object in its DataContext (passed there by property value inheritance from the parent element of the control).

Comment: If you need the same set of properties in multiple control classes, create a common base class.

Comment: hey! Im kind of new to wpf and mvvm i didnt exactly knew how to get the Navigation part done of my app. Like every solution i found was with ContentControl - UserControls and their own VM, so sorry for that ^^. Thanks for your answer tho, ill try that out.

Comment: to the guy that downvoted without explaining why : wtf?

Comment: you can also use ninject

Comment: I doubt you have to use dependency injection for this - its a bit of an overkill. The proposed solution @rejy11 posted is correct, you can create a base ViewModel that these UserControls can inherit from, and they will all have the Email and Language property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a ViewModelBase class with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (usually standard in an MVVM app) then simply add you're two strings here. All of you're subsequent ViewModels will inherit these properties, eliminating the need to implement the two properties in each of your ViewModels.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

If you mark the class and the properties as abstract, this would force derived classes to override the two properties.